# Why doesn't FTPClient.setDefaultTimeout work?

Tags: java, timeout, ftp-client

I am trying to make a ftp connection in Java with FTPClient.
I wanted to look what happens when i separate the line between Server and Client. My application freezed about 30seconds and then it thows a `ConnectionException`(Connection timed out). Thats why I searched for a timeout method for the FTPCliend and I found `setDefaultTimeout()` so I put the method before the connection attemp but it still freezed 30 sec...

```
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
    ftp.connect(ip);
```

When i put "1.1.1.1" as `ip` the application throws fastly a `ConnectionException`(Connection refused) but when i put the right ipAdress its just freezing(30sec) and threwing the `ConnectionException` instead of the wished TimeoutException (after 5sec)

What am I doing wrong?

ps: excuse my horrible english knowledge ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which `FTPClient` you're using because there are a couple out there.  However, they usually have two different timeout options : one for data and one for actual connection.  I suggest you search for a method called `setConnectTimeout()` or similar.

Comment: there are [this](http://sudhirvn.blogspot.com/2007/05/ftpclient-timeout-values.html) 3 different Timeouts possiblities.

Comment: oh and its from the apache commons library

Comment: Ah, so it's commons-net.  What version are you using?  The [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for 3.0.1 shows that it has a whole bunch more than that article lists, including the `setConnectTimeout()`.

Comment: oh I had an old version. I'll try with the new library version ;)